# Hibernate uses old closed SessionImpl instead of given SessionImpl

Tags: ajax, hibernate, jsf, hibernate-envers

I have a problem with Hibernate Enverse (Version 5.2.0-Final).

**Context:**
I'm auditing some entities with some lazy relations. I have a jsf-page that loads one version of one entity with all relations of that version. That works fine. So now I have a page that shows a revision of the entity with all relations of that revision. On this page I can open a fieldset, that triggers an AJAX. In this request we reattach all relations by calling `entityManager.merge(entity)` to be able to fetch the lazy relations in this fieldset. (The EntityManager is RequestScoped)

**The Problem:**
The AJAX is a new request. The server calls `entityManager.merge(entity)`, what enforces creation of a new EntityManager (So a new `org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl` is created). On this object hibernate calls `SessionImpl.merge(...)`. But in the method `org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(String)` a other SessionImpl object is used, which is already closed in the request before. That enforces an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed`.

**In one sentence**: Although a new entityManager was created and a merge was called on that new entityManger, Hibernate uses an old Session/EntityManager of the request before.

I debugged the problem and found following:

- [Debug1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muABq.png): Shows the Stacktrace of the `SessionImpl.merge(...)` with the session's object id
- [Debug2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7zc7.png): Shows the last method with the correct SessionImpl object (see it's id). This object is not used in next methods.
- [Debug3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxsQM.png): The step after Debug2 does not know the given SessionImpl object. It has it's own SessionImpl object in `collection.initializor.versionsReader`. This session was created and closed in the request before (on loading the page).
- [Debug4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyV2V.png): Now Hibernate wants to create the query wit the closed SessionImpl
- [Debug5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXsgb.png): This enforces the exception, as the session is closed.

**My questions**:

- Is this a bug of Hibernate?
- Why is the given SessionImpl in method `org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getElementIterater(...)` not used?
- Anyone knows a solution or workaround for this problem?

Tank you very much for any idea. I spent days on this bug.

Comment: Sure that `entityManager.merge(entity)` creates a new entitymanager? I thought it just merges the entity to the entitymanager you call merge on (and the **returned** object should be used, not `'enity'`

Comment: Yes, the entityManager is RequestScoped. On every request, that uses the entityManager, a new SessionImpl object is created and at the end of the request it will be closed. (Proofed that with debugger). But it is not created on every merge-Call, only at the first use of the enttiyManger in a request.

Comment: But the entity manager is not specifiaclly created by that call (it might implicitly be). Also read the second part of my comment!!!

Comment: When you fetch the audited instance of the entity from the Envers Query API, are you making sure that the collections are being initialized before you cache and reuse the instance in the subsequent ajax-request that results in working with a completely new `Session`?  I somewhat believe all this about 'merge' is irrelevant because that has nothing to do with the problem with the collection initializor in  your _Debug3_ screen-shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the `Session` arg in `o.h.type.CollectionType.getElementIterator` not used?

The short answer is it isn't required, its simply a backward compatibility concern from 8 years ago.

The long answer is the type-system used to actually deviate some behavior based on whether or not the user had specified the session to operate in `EntityMode.MAP` or `EntityMode.POJO` and therefore the types needed to know what mode the session was in; hence why it was passed.

But even back in 2011 when this was changed, the session argument only ever influenced behavior *if and only if* the session was operating in `EntityMode.MAP`.  In other words, all other modes always routed directly to the underlying collections `Collection#iterator()` method.

All this aside however, this doesn't have any impact on what you experience in your *Debug3* screen-shot.

> Is this a bug in Hibernate?

No, based on what I have read, I believe you're mixing concerns.

In Hibernate (no Envers), you can basically do this

```
// Request 1
request1EntityManager = getEntityManager();
sessionScopeEntity = request1EntityManager.find( MyEntity.class, myEntityId );

// Request 2
request2EntityManager = getEntityManager();
sessionScopeEntity = request2EntityManager.merge( sessionScopeEntity );
for ( SomeCollectionItem Item : sessionScopeEntity.getSomeCollection() ) {
  // do things here
}
```

The above works because you reassociate the entity with the new session which in-turn injects the session into all the uninitialized proxies the entity maintains.  But you can also rewrite the above as

```
// Request 1
request1EntityManager = getEntityManager();
sessionScopeEntity = request1EntityManager.find( MyEntity.class, myEntityId );
sessionScopeEntity.getSomeCollection().size() // initialize collection w/request1Session

// Request 2
request2EntityManager = getEntityManager();
for ( SomeCollectionItem Item : sessionScopeEntity.getSomeCollection() ) {
  // do things here
}
```

The difference is the collection gets initialized with the first session and therefore when you attempt to access it with the second session, the entity doesn't necessarily need a merge because the collection is no longer a proxy but actually populated like a normal fetched collection would be.

**The major difference between an entity instance returned by Hibernate and an audited entity instance returned by Envers is that the audited entity instance is NOT a managed persistent entity.**

Depending on your scenario, you may decide to only audit a subset of fields on an entity mapping.  This is why you cannot nor should not use things like `merge` with that instance as it could easily lead to unintended side effects with your real data.

If you intend to pass the audited entity instance across sessions, i would highly suggest that you instead consider initializing the collections you need up-front with the first session where you fetched the instance because presently there is no way to re-associate an audited entity instance with a new session.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I reload the audited Entity by it's PRIMARY-KEY and the revision number. That works fine.